# Can this CSS with multiple classes be simplified any further?

Tags: css, wordpress, class, coding-style

```
.page-id-247 .entry-title, .page-id-112 .entry-title  {
  display:none;
}
```

Trying to learn ways to clean up my code, and simplify things.  Curious if this can be cleaner by only having `.entry-title` stated once somehow.

Comment: It is fine...you can't simplify it further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends upon the body of the cody. You can cut the code to .entery-tile as you are applying the same style to both the class or you can use attribute selector like [class*=page]{ display: none;} to apply the same code in all the class with page. It all really depends on your code and what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As per I understand if you want to simplify then you need to create a general class which you can use it at all place. And use this class with `.entry-title` class. Please refer following code:

```
.display-none {
   display: none;
}
```